# WSO2 ESB startup error - H2 database unable to delete row

Tags: wso2, h2, wso2-esb

WSO2 ESB goes into error state on startup.

During startup, the following H2 database error is thrown.

> org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Row not found when trying to delete from
>   index

Due to some data corruption, the following error occurs. Restarts didnt help.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WSO2 products has an inbuilt H2 database. Though its sufficient for DEV environments, Its not recommended for production.

For the above error, the H2 DB has been corrupted. To fix, rename the existing 
$CARBON_HOME/databases/ folder and create an empty **databases** folder.

Start the server, with `-Dsetup` option as ./`wso2server.sh -Dsetup`
This will recreate a new DB setup and populate the required data.

Answer (score 0):

We need more information... ¿What do you need? , restart and recover all the resources in your install or just restart and keep working.

1.- Make a backup copy of all databases files in $CARBON_HOME/databases/ folder
2.- Restart a clean instances removing the corrupted database, remove all the H2 files in $CARBON_HOME/databases/ folder. If you have all your artifacts in $CARBON_HOME/deployment it should rebuild all.